# How to change font-size of vscode developer tool

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

The default font size of vscode developer tool (ctrl+shift+i) is too small for high dpi monitor and I want to make it bigger.
I do not find exact solution for it and I tried following related operations, but none of them works:

##### 1. Set Window: Zoom Level

This configuration change size of everything except for the debugger tool, wired.

##### 2. Set Editor:Font Size and Debug>Console: Font Size.

Still not affects the debugger tools.

##### 3. Directy ctrl+scroll up/down using mouse

Not working. But works for editor if corresponding switch is on.

##### 4. Configuration inside Developer tool.

Found no entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you can try this.
...\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\workbench.desktop.main.css,
modify the font-size which is 11px to what you want .
(but it just effects the fonts in interface, not the variables in debug)

and is that ctrl+'+' not useful?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1jpt.png)

Comment: ctrl+"num pad +" works!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size with <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. It remembers the size when you close and reopen the devtools and when you close and reopen VS Code (perhaps this may not have been true before (I haven't been keeping track)).